# Laravel. Can not use Carbon while querying with DB facade

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I need to allocate several appointments inside a calendar, looping through employee, day and hour.

**First option** I did it in frontend like this. Using ELOQUENT in back end

I have a loop inside a loop as you could see here:

```
@for($i = 8; $i <= 17; $i++) // This are the hours. From 9:00 hour to 17:00 hour (German hour format)

    @foreach($employee->appointments as $appointment) // I take the appointment of each employee

        @if( $appointment->date->translatedFormat('D j M') != today()->translatedFormat('D j M')) 

            @continue //if the appointment is not from today, continue

        @else
            @if( $appointment->date->format('H') != $i )
                <h3> <a href="link_to_create_appointment_form">Add an appointment</a></h3>
                // insert a link to create a new apppointment
            @else
                // insert the Appointment
            @endif

        @endif
    @endforeach
@endfor
```

But after the first appointment is inserted (Appointment == today && now()), the foreach goes to next appointment, but start from the beginning.

At the end if I have an appointment at 9:00 and another at 10:00 I get the following:

1. 8:00 - add an appointment
2. 09:00 - APPOINTMENT 1
3. 8:00 - add an appointment
4. 9:00 - add an appointment
5. 10:00 - APPOINTMENT 2

**Second option** is to use DB facade and JOIN several  tables (appointments, clients, employees and openingtimes).

This results in a most faster solution in a single loop.

The problem is that DB Facade does noot allows the use of Carbon ans I get the following error:

```
{{ $appointment->date->format('H:i') }}
```

This is my query:

```
$todayAppointments = DB::table('appointments')
            ->leftJoin('clients', 'appointments.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
            ->leftJoin('employees', 'employees.user_id', '=', 'employees.id')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'appointments.employee_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->whereDay('appointments.date', today())
            ->selectRaw(
                'users.id AS id,
                users.firstname AS employee,
                clients.firstname AS clientname,
                clients.lastname AS clientlastname,
                clients.lastname AS clientlastname,
                clients.gender_id AS clientgender,
                appointments.duration AS duration,
               appointments.date AS date'
            )
            ->groupBy('users.id', 'clients.id', 'appointments.id')
            ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
            ->get();
```

**QUESTION:**
How could I convert the result of DB facade to a Carbon format in order to make things like this:

```
$appointment->date->format('H') != $i
```

I have tried the whole day using @loop, @index, but with not success.

Comment: "The DB Facade does not allow Carbon and I get the following error" - it looks like you forgot to include the error in your question. To clarify, the DB facade works fine for _querying_ with Carbon (or anything implementing DateTimeInterface), but the `date` field it returns from your database is a _string_ , not a _Carbon instance_. Using `Carbon::parse($appointment->date)` should give you a Carbon object if you need it, but this logic can be achieved without resorting to the DB facade.

Comment: Why don't you simply write a SQL query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$appointment->date` isn't a `Carbon` instance if you use the `DB::table()` method, as `Carbon` instantiation is done via `protected $dates = [];` on the Model. `DB::table()` returns each record (`$appointment`) as a `StdClass` object, and no an instance of an `Appointment` model. Either use the model to start the query (create the model if you don't have one), or instantiate a `Carbon` instance before formatting:

In `Appointment.php`:

```
 protected $dates = ["date"];
```

In your `Controller`:

```
$todayAppointments = Appointment::leftJoin(...)->get();
```

In your `view.blade.php`:

```
@foreach($todayAppointments AS $appointment)
{{ $appointment->date->format("H:i") }}
@endforeach
```

Or, if you want to use the `DB::table()` approach:

In your `view.blade.php`:

```
@foreach($todayAppointments AS $appointment)
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($appointment->date)->format("H:i") }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: The first option does not work. Is the way I did it. I will try the second one. (I am not in front of the computer right now)

Comment: No worries, test when you can, but you'll have to clarify what "does not work" means though; that's a little vague.